# Why does 'pis-aller' mean 'dernier ressort'?

Tags: étymologie

[E. Cobham Brewer 1810–1897. Dictionary of Phrase and Fable. 1898.](https://www.bartleby.com/81/13315.html) defines 'pis-aller' as 'dernier ressort'. English [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pis_aller) translates the etymons.

> From [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language) *[pis-aller](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pis-aller#French)*, from *[pis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pis#French)* (“worst”) + *[aller](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller#French)* (“to go”).

But neither expounds the etymology. I can understand how "pis ressort", if this exists, can signify 'dernier ressort'. But I'm befuddled because "aller" doesn't signify "ressort".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to make it clear: "pis-aller" precisely means "to go with the worse choice". It's basically a poor workaround, doing what we can with what we have.

"Dernier ressort" is literally "the last chance, the last way out". "Une solution de dernier ressort" is somewhat worse than a "pis-aller": it's "the very last chance" vs "not the preferred or best choice".

Answer (score 3):

*Pis ressort* doesn't make sense in French.

Anyway, the reason why *aller* doesn't mean *ressort* is because *pis* doesn't mean *dernier*.

*Pis* is the neutral form of *pire*, maybe the only word that survived the neutral case disappearance in French, and means "worse".

*Aller* is the substantivated form of the verb *aller* (to go), so *pis-aller* literally means something like "worse way, worse solution" but is mostly used nowadays to mean an unsatisfactory workaround, something doomed.